# vb.net OLEDB Parametarize query

Tags: oledb

When i put parameter in my OLEDB code it compile successfully but it doesn't do the task. For example this delete data code:

```
    Try
        If dbconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbconn.Open()
        End
        Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        dbCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM UsersTB WHERE First_Name =?"
        dbCommand.Connection = dbconn
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row", 0)
        Dim rows = dgvusers.SelectedRows
        For Each row In rows
            dbCommand.Parameters("@row").Value = row.Cells("First_Name").Value
            dbCommand.Connection = dbconn
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        MsgBox("Deleted")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ex.ToString()
    End Try
```

This code is written on button when i compiled and click the button it doesn't delete the data i tried putting it on try catch and putting msgbox to indicate if the command is successful it and it indicate its "Deleted" but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are setting rows = dgvusers.SelectedRows, and have you verified that any rows are selected.  Have you checked the row.Cells("First_Name").Value for any text in your for each loop?  Check that the are records in the database for the value as well.

Comment: Im trying to add a button delete that will delete the data from my database on the selected row in the datagridview. How can I make this work?